# How to write from Xpages to PostgreSql database?

Tags: postgresql, xpages, lotus-domino, lotus

I have to create an Xpage web application which directly inputs data in a PostgreSql database. I've never worked with a PostgreSql database so I have absolutely no idea on how to approach this.

The application will be used through a browser if that matters.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or, if you do not want to use the extLib for this purpose only, take a look at http://www.eknori.de/2011-07-03/using-mysql-data-in-xpages/ The article describes, how to access MySQL, but you can use the same code even for PstGreSQL with the correct JDBC drive.
The article also contains a link to OpenNTF where you can download the full source code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a JDBC connection to connect to PostgreSQL. Use the extension library. This library contains a demo application which connects to a sql database using JDBC. Please take a look at this question : [How do I access SQL from XPages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026052/how-do-i-access-sql-from-xpages).